# Nibabel does not load slope and inter parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, nifti, nibabel

I am saving some nparray into nifti format using `nibabel` package. I specify a slope and intercept value in order to scale data back to their original format. However, the scale and intercept information are not available anymore when I load back the data. Here is a code snippet to reproduce the behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

# Create dumb 3D data:
img=np.ones((20,20,5),dtype=np.uint16)

# Create an affine matrix:
affine=np.eye(4)

# Create nifti
nii=nib.Nifti1Image(img,affine=affine)

# Set slope and inter values
nii.header.set_slope_inter(slope=1,inter=0)

# Save the nifti on disk
nib.save(nii,'test.nii')

# Load back the data
nii2=nib.load('test.nii')

# Get the slope and inter
print(nii2.header.get_slope_inter())

# It returns (None, None)
```

The output is `(None,None)`, despite the fact that `nii2.header.has_data_slope` and  `nii2.header.has_data_intercept` both return True.

I opened the nifti file with other nifti reader such as mango and itk-snap, and could check that the slope and intercept are correctly displayed.

Is this a bug?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug. This behavior is noted in Nibabel's [docs](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html#data-scaling).

When first created/loaded, a nifti1 object (Nibabel image) has a scale slope and intercept accessible as:

```
import nibabel as nib

# load the image
im = nib.load("image.nii.gz")

# get scale slope/inter values
scale_slope = im.dataobj.slope
scale_intercept = im.dataobj.inter

# scale_slope and scale_intercept won't be None and None, but the following:
slope_inter = im.header.get_slope_inter()

# will probably print (None, None)
print("slope_inter: %r" % (slope_inter,))
```

To answer your question, after calling set_slope_inter() the new values you set are available at:

```
image.dataobj.slope
image.dataobj.inter
```

It's a bit late, but I hope it'll help someone!